# Display all parent categories/ subcategories on product view Magento

Tags: php, magento

My category structure :

MAIN CATEGORIES > MANUFACTURERS > PRINTER MODELS

etc...

I want display on product view all printer models compatible with cartridge.

I use the following code :

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>

<?php
     foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id):
     $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)
?>
<?php echo $_category->getName().'<span class="slash-imprimantes"> / </span>' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem it display only Printer Models but i want display Manufacturers too

Eg. CANON PRINTER MODEL1 / CANON PRINTER MODEL2 / CANON PRINTER MODEL 3 / HP PRINTER MODEL 4 / HP PRINTER MODEL 5 / HP PRINTER MODEL 6

How can i proceed ?

And if i want alphabetical sort order ?